# Unexpected "/" in <filepath> while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I've set up an EJS partial under a path `views/partials/ejspartial.ejs` which I am trying to access in an ejs file with the path `views/ejsfile.ejs`. This is the same views directory.

In the `ejsfile.ejs`, I've added the following line of code: `<% include ./partials/ejspartial %>`

When I load the ejsfile page, I get the following error:

> `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '/' in <path>/views/ejsfile while compiling ejs`

I've tried swapping in the `<%-` tag and removing the `./` from the `include` statement, but the same error occurs.

Comment: the include is correct, its something else. post the contents of `<path>/views/ejsfile.ejs` or look for some odd `/`

Comment: I placed the contents of the partial directly into the ejsfile replacing the `include` portion. It works as intended. I'm just trying to reference it in the ejs partial instead of directly into the view.

Comment: Can you post `views/ejsfile.ejs`?

Comment: Try `<%- include('partials/ejspartial') %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is because you are using the syntax of an older version of EJS.

I notice that the [docs](https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes) say: "NOTE: Include preprocessor directives (`<% include user/show %>`) are still supported."

However, the [owner](https://github.com/mde) of the EJS repository says otherwise here: https://github.com/tj/ejs/issues/220

I would try the new syntax, `<%- include('partials/ejspartial') %>`, and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: This worked. I was missing the single quotes inside of the parenthesis. Thank you!!

Comment: Awesome! Can you accept my answer as correct for people facing a similar issue then?